# PyQGIS - ComboBox - update selection in procedural programming

Tags: pyqgis, combo-box

I have a polygon shapefile (p_cities) and I want to present a simple GUI to the user to select a city from a combobox and that city will be highlighted & zoomed in.

The following code does it for the first city appearing in the combobox, but it does not continue working even if I change my selection in the combobox:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


lyrName = "p_cities"
lyr = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(lyrName)[0]
idx = lyr.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex( 'name' ) 
uv = lyr.dataProvider().uniqueValues( idx )
cb = QComboBox()
cb.addItems( uv )
cb.show()    
cityName = cb.currentText()

c = lyr.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(u' "name" ILIKE \'%s\' ' %cityName))
lyr.setSelectedFeatures([s.id() for s in c])
iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
```

It seems that I need to dig into the signals and slots and use "currentIndexChanged" accordingly. However, it would also be great if I could learn doing it in procedural programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a big deal, you just have to create a function for the zoom & highlight action and connect it to your comboBox.

The following code should works:

```
def zoomTo():
    cityName = cb.currentText()
    c = lyr.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(u' "name" ILIKE \'%s\' ' %cityName))
    lyr.setSelectedFeatures([s.id() for s in c])
    iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
lyrName = "p_cities"
lyr = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(lyrName)[0]
idx = lyr.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex( 'name' ) 
uv = lyr.dataProvider().uniqueValues( idx )
cb = QComboBox()
cb.addItems( uv )
cb.show()

cb.currentIndexChanged.connect(zoomTo)
```